# PHP if condition not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am having some problems with setting the value of "swimsuit" variable as defined below, however when I set the value to "1" in my MYSQL database, it sets $real=true but elsewise it says "real is undefined".

```
$query4 = "SELECT swimsuit FROM player_equipment WHERE player_name='xhyderz'";
$result = mysql_query($query4,$link);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$swim = $row['swimsuit'];
$real=null;
if($swim==0){
    $real=false;
}else{
    $real=true;
}
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var swimsuit=".$real."; </script>";
```

Comment: If you echo a boolean false it prints nothing so your javascript won't work as is

Comment: You just can write: `$real='true';
if($swim==0)$real='false';`

Comment: Note, you are using [deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) functions, consider using `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
if($swim==0){
    $real="false";
}else{
    $real="true";
}
```

Edit:

Look at cbuckley's explaination, way more clear and complete than mine.

Answer (score 4):

When you concatenate a boolean variable with a string like that, you get the following:

```
var_dump(true  . ""); // "1"
var_dump(false . ""); // ""
```

So if `$real` is `false`, your JavaScript looks like:

```
var swimsuit=;
```

You can either use the strings `"true"` or `"false"` for `$real`, or you can use `json_encode`:

```
echo "var swimsuit=" . json_encode($real) . ";";
```